# Preventing possibility of conflicting foreign keys

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design, entity-framework-core

I am using SQL Server through EF Core 5 with an existing database. For the sake of this question, I have three tables: Customers, Assets, Loans. A Loan is made to a Customer and is based off the value of an Asset, which belongs to a Customer.

Customers have a one to many relationship with Loans. Customers have a one to many relationship with Assets. Assets have a one to many relationship with Loans

In the Loans table, I currently have a foreign key to Customers (to track who is responsible for the Loan) and a foreign key to Assets (to track which asset this Loan was made against).

I'm trying to find the best way to prevent conflicting foreign keys from being created in the Loans table (i.e., a record with one Customer, but then a Asset that is associated with a different Customer). I can do this at a code level, but I would prefer to have it done at the database level so that any changes to the code won't accidentally affect this integrity check.

I was thinking about deleting the Customer foreign key from Loans since I can get the Customer through the Assets foreign key. But I am worried about performance, and the most common query is to get a list of all Loans associated with a Customer and I can do that without needing the Assets table by filtering all Loans with a certain CustomerID.

Is there a way to make sure that an Asset with a Customer that is different than the Customer in the Loan table is not allowed at the database level?

Or should I not worry about the performance issue, and get rid of the Customer foreign key in the Loans table?

Comment: Hmmm... thats a tricky one. Personally I would keep it as it is, but not for performance reasons (SQL Server can handle a couple of joins no problem), but for logical reasons. Logically a Customer owns an Asset and owns the Loan. As Asset doesn't own a Loan, nor does a Loan own an Asset. To ensure integrity I would probably put a Check Constraint or Trigger on both the Loan and Asset tables to ensure they are never owned by different customers.

Comment: A Check Constraint is neater assuming you can have both on the same column (I've never tried), but you need a scalar function which isn't great for performance, hence I would probably go with a trigger.

Comment: Is this just a school project or something for the real world? I expect it's not uncommon for the same Asset to be used as security for multiple Loans over its lifetime, e.g: homes and home loans. The same Asset could be used as security for multiple loans made to the same Customer, or different Customers, such when the home changes possession and a new loan gets financed with the old one getting (or already) paid out.

Answer (score 1):

**You can, but it doesn't mean you should.**

First thing I see,

> Assets have a one to many relationship with Loans

In real life, things aren't that simple; a lender might require more security for the loan, and the borrower will have to provide [additional collateral](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/a/additional-collateral.asp) to secure it. That turns the relationship into M:M, and you will need an additional table, let's call it `LoanCollaterals`, which will implement this link.

Something like this:

[image: Multiple collaterals per loan]

Now, you can migrate the `CustomerId` column along both `LoanCollaterals`'s foreign keys, using the approach demonstrated in the answer from @seanb. This will create a schema-level constraint that ensures the asset always belongs to the customer who is taking the loan. However, I would strongly recommend against this approach:

1. It makes impossible for multiple borrowers to share the same asset. You will have to create a new `Asset` record for the same collateral, but this time "belonging" to another customer. Bankers won't be happy when they will hear it.
2. Most people freak out at the sight of multi-column foreign keys, and are unable to comprehend the concept.
3. Scale-up: for a school project this approach might hold, but any real world system of any complexity worth mentioning will soon become bloated with these redundant columns. I've seen a DWH model once which had 5 levels of keys migrated this way. Not pretty.
4. More links result in a more tightly-coupled entities. Reworks / expansions of such model will be considerably more challenging in the future.

In short, these kinds of checks / constraints are what stored procedures are for. You can perform all necessary validations inside the procedure, within a controlled transaction, and either create a record or throw an error to the client app, if anything doesn't satisfy the requirements. Of course, you can implement an equivalent functionality using EF, but it won't be as efficient, as it would require a client-side transaction and several app-to-DB roundtrips to perform all these business logic checks.

Comment: I have to admit, I really dislike Foreign Keys *constraints* in databases (particularly for transaction data) and use them very sparingly, and once the logic is well known. I also prefer your model/logic for setup (though I would go further with Asset setup etc e.g., there is no requirement that an asset must be owned by a customer - it could be their parents) and assume, over time, they will migrate to a similar approach. However, the key part of their current question was how to set up FKs to ensure that the Asset is owned by the same customer.

Comment: @seanb, I agree that I wasn't completely on topic, however with my experience the question essentially falls into the "how I can shoot myself in a foot" category. And that's what my answer is about: "you can, but you won't like the result".

Comment: As far as I see it, in the above you should dissociate assets from customers (e.g., random Joe Bloggs guaranteed $20k) and then make a loan_collateral table as you have. However, as per the OP's original question, part of their problem is that they would want to put CustomerID into that table too (so they can get all collateral for a person without going through loans). And at that point, you fundamentally have an analagous structure to the original (with loans and assets reordered into loans and collateral) and you're back to the original problem - how to set up FKs.

Comment: @seanb, in that case the `LoanCollaterals` would violate 3NF (I believe) as it references a non-prime `CustomerId` attribute. The argument of "saving on an extra join" is a very lame excuse for that. But that's only relevant for "proper" database design, is it?..

Answer (score 0):

In Loans, the foreign key constraint for Customers could be pointed to Assets instead (to both AssetID and CustomerID). As there is a foreign key in Assets to Customers, the FKs should hold in enforcing correct data.

Note that FKs do not need to point to PKs - however they do need to point to unique records - hence the Unique constraint in Assets I've put below.

The below structure and approach assumes loans *do not have to have* an Asset backing. If it does, add a `NOT NULL` to the AssetID column in Loans table.

```
CREATE TABLE Customers (CustomerID int PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE Assets (AssetID int PRIMARY KEY, CustomerID int NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE Loans (LoanID int PRIMARY KEY, CustomerID int NOT NULL, AssetID int);

-- Standard FKs you already have
ALTER TABLE Assets
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Assets_Customers FOREIGN KEY (CustomerID) 
REFERENCES Customers(CustomerID);

ALTER TABLE Loans
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Loans_Customers FOREIGN KEY (CustomerID) 
REFERENCES Customers(CustomerID);

-- Enforces a unique combination of CustomerID and AssetID in Assets 
-- (need unique constraint for FK to point to)
ALTER TABLE Assets 
ADD CONSTRAINT UC_Assets_CA UNIQUE (CustomerID, AssetID);

-- FK which enforces combination of CustomerID and AssetID is valid.
ALTER TABLE Loans
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Loans_Assets FOREIGN KEY (CustomerID, AssetID) 
REFERENCES Assets(CustomerID, AssetID);
```

For demonstration purposes, here are some queries

```
-- These work
INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerID) VALUES (100);
INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerID) VALUES (101);
INSERT INTO Assets (AssetID, CustomerID) VALUES (200, 100);
INSERT INTO Assets (AssetID, CustomerID) VALUES (201, 101);
INSERT INTO Loans (LoanID, CustomerID, AssetID) VALUES (300, 100, 200);

-- This also works - where loan doesn't have an asset
-- (see notes above if you do not want this to happen - add a NOT NULL
-- to table definition)
INSERT INTO Loans (LoanID, CustomerID) VALUES (400, 100);

-- These don't work
INSERT INTO Loans (LoanID, CustomerID, AssetID) VALUES (500, 100, 1);
INSERT INTO Loans (LoanID, CustomerID) VALUES (600, 1);

-- Importantly, for your question - the following does NOT work 
-- because the Customer and Assets don't match
INSERT INTO Loans (LoanID, CustomerID, AssetID) VALUES (700, 101, 200);
-- ... however this one does work (assets/customers are valid)
INSERT INTO Loans (LoanID, CustomerID, AssetID) VALUES (700, 101, 201);
```